# Replace text of editText on click of keypad (virtual keypad)

Tags: android-edittext

My editText having default value as "000".When i am clicking on any number suppose 5,my editText should show me "005".Then again i am clicking on 6 it should now showing me "056".These effect will happen on click of number on my keyboard(virtual)not on click of done button on that keyboard.
How should i proceed.
        Please help me for this.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below (assuming you have an editText1 already defined in your layout)

```
     import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    editText1.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
    {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {     
        editText1.setText(keyCode);
        return true; // return true if you handled the keypress 
        }
    });
}
}
```